# View definitions in MariaDB are not create with mysqldump

Tags: mysql, backup, mariadb

I have a db in MariaDB 10.1.25 and in this, I have many tables and 20 views.
When I try to backup my db using mysqldump, it works fine for tables but in view definitions, it fails to create a create statement like it does with tables. 
The code generated is this:

```
--
-- Temporary table structure for view `qry_clientes`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `qry_clientes`;
/*!50001 DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `qry_clientes`*/;
SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client;
SET character_set_client = utf8;
/*!50001 CREATE TABLE `qry_clientes` (
  `Id` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `Cliente` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `Direccion` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `Ciudad` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `Fono` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `Fax` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `Email` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `Ruc` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `tipo` tinyint NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM */;
SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client;
```

and in this there are no view definitions. I have all the privilegies grandted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, in the mysqldump backup script, the views are first created as tables and then are then dropped at the bottom of the script as each view is being created.

Sometimes there is an error in this process because when a view is created there is a user used as DEFINER. This statement may fail because this user might not exist in the database.

Please verify that the view drop/create script exists at the end, write the error that you are getting (if you are getting) and run the import using the -v option for more logging.

Comment: yes it is correct I create de dump file and compress it and then load as import file via phpmysadmin in the other pc and run successfully

Comment: I am glad I could help my friend :)